# Moment js is not working for january (month 0)

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I know in moment months are 0 indexed. Basically I set this.month to any integer from 0 to 11 and run the following code. For some reason it doesn't want to update the moment variable for the month January (which has the number 0). What is wrong and how do I fix?

```js
const d: Moment = moment();
if (this.month) d.month(this.month);
console.log("Month value: " + this.month);
console.log("Moment value: " + d.month());
```

Console.log returns the following for this.month = 2 (March)

Month value: 2
Moment value: 2

Console.log returns the following for this.month = 1 (February)

Month value: 1
Moment value: 1

Console.log returns the following for this.month = 0 (January)

**Month value: 0**
**Moment value: 1**

Comment: What does `this` refer to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (this.month)
```

The following instruction won't run if `this.month` is a falsy value (like 0).

As HMR suggested, you may want to use the `===` operator (or its negation `!==`) to check that `this.month` isn't `null` nor `undefined`.

Comment: Dafuq... then how would I check it?

Comment: @coding_pianist `if(this.month!==undefined)`

Comment: @coding_pianist nobody but you has any idea what `this` is in your code, or what possible values `this.month` might contain. What did you expect the `if` statement to test?

Comment: @HMR Thanks! 
@Pointy I use typescript and `this.month` is of type `number | null`, so I thought the if statement would think `this.month` was a number if `this.month == 0`, since 0, to my knowledge, is a number. When I check if `this.month !== null` the code works as I intended. `this` I guess refers to that `this.month` is part of the class which the code resides in? Sorry, should have clarified that!